# Какие варианты предлагает google для публикации контента созданного пользователем

Tags: android, google-play

В моем приложении пользователи создают контент в виде бинарных файлов (электрические схемы, рисунки, комментарии, описание работы, монтажные платы).

Какие варианты предлагает google для публикации файлов из приложения?

Чтобы пользователи смогли оценить творчество друг друга, обсудить недостатки, предложить улучшения. Хочется при этом что бы пользователь оставался в привычном ему интерфейсе приложения.

Сейчас я рассматриваю вариант с созданием сайта, но мне кажется это сложным и дорогим вариантом, возможно есть уже готовые решения от google или других компаний.

Какие варианты предлагает google для публикации контента созданного пользователем?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю подойдет [Firebase Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).

Comment: у вас был опыт работы с этой системой? не могу найти сколько это стоит?

Comment: @FatherOfFiveChildren Все бесплатно с разумными лимитами. Прямо с этой нет, с другими компонентами FireBase был небольшой.